# Move a file in S3 to a new folder with the same name

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli, boto

I have an AWS S3 bucket with hundreds of files in it. I want to create a new folder for each file, and I want the folders to have the same name as the files.

Basically, from this:

```
bucket_name/
├── filename1.json
├── filename2.json
├── filename3.json
└── ...
```

To this:

```
bucket_name/
├── filename1/ 
|     └── filename1.json
├── filename2/ 
|     └── filename2.json
├── filename3/ 
|     └── filename3.json
└── ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you really want a Windows batch file for this? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the a for loop with where + mkdir, using file name to create folder:

```
Rem :: in command line ::
for /F %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where ".:*.json" ')do mkdir .\"%~ni" && move "%~i” .\"%~ni"

Rem :: in cmd/bat file ::
@echo off & for /F %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where ".:*.json" ')do mkdir .\"%%~ni" && move "%%~i” .\"%%~ni"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've included the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag, here's one possible method:

```bat
@Set "SourceDir=..\Desktop\New folder"
@For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%I In ('""%__APPDIR__%where.exe" "$SourceDir:*.json" 2>NUL"'
)Do @"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%~dpI." "%%~dpI%%~nI" "%%~nxI" /Mov>NUL
```

Simply replace the path of your source directory on line `1` to that holding your `.json` files, *(I have used a relative path, yours can be relative or full as necessary)*.